# send Http Request to part of another website

Tags: asp.net

I want to send HTTP Web request to part of another website for example that websites have many panel as if updated by AJAX in general I decide send my request to specified panel.
how?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can use [HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Details
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18034/HttpWebRequest-Response-in-a-Nutshell-Part-1